# How do i remove an array object if the array is not made by an ArrayList?

Tags: java, arrays

I am trying to remove a meteor in my game for when it his a bullet but there seems to be an error, and I do not now another method to remove the object.

```
for (int i = 0; i < numA; i++) {
    if (meteor[i].isVisible())
      meteor[i].move();
    else meteor[i].remove(i);
    }
```

Comment: `meteor[i].remove(i);` This is calling the remove() method on the meteor object, not the array. Is that what you wanted?

Comment: I am trying to remove the meteor that visible is false, once it is hit by an object

Answer (score 4):

You know, you should actually use a `Set` for that. An array is much too inefficient.

To do this, instead of declaring an array:

```
private Meteor[] meteor = new Meteor[10];
```

declare a `Set`:

```
private Set<Meteor> meteor = new HashSet<Meteor>();
```

You can add meteors:

```
meteor.add(newMeteor);
```

and remove them:

```
meteor.remove(meteorToRemove);
```

and check if they are in the set:

```
if (meteor.contains(met))
```

and iterate through them:

```
for (Meteor m : meteor)
```

Comment: Admittedly, anything that is a `Collection` has a `remove` and `contains` method, not just a `Set`.  You're only then (trying to) guarantee that duplicate `Meteor` objects aren't placed into the collection.  Not sure if that's what is desired, but for this to work to its fullest potential, `equals()` and `hashCode()` have to be overridden in `Meteor`.

Comment: @Makoto I'm trying to pick the most efficint solution. `HashSet` would be the most efficient way to store a bunch of `Meteor`s. I don't say to overide `equals` and `hashCode` because each `Meteor` should probably be considered distinct.

Comment: It isn't going to work as well as you think if two instances of `Meteor` hash to the same value.  That's precisely why you have to override hashCode (and you really should override equals, since that's the general contract of overriding those two).  There is a difference between efficient and broken code.

Comment: @Makoto The default implementation of `hashCode` makes it very, very unlikely that two different instances of `Meteor` has to the same value. If they do, `equals` is overridden to use the `==` operator. There can't possibly be a problem with this.

Answer (score 1):

Apache has a commons utility method in `ArrayUtils` that could help. It works like this:

`array = ArrayUtils.removeElement(meteor, elementToDelete)`

Check out the docs for more info: [Apache Docs](http://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-lang/apidocs/org/apache/commons/lang3/ArrayUtils.html#removeElement%28T%5B%5D,%20java.lang.Object%29)

Answer (score 0):

## array only solution

```
for (int i = 0; i < numA; i++) {
    if (meteor[i].isVisible())
        meteor[i].move();
    else {
        Meteor[] result = new Meteor[meteor.length - 1];
        System.arraycopy(meteor, 0, result, 0, i);
        if (meteor.length != i) {
            System.arraycopy(meteor, i + 1, result, i, meteor.length - i - 1);
        }
        meteor = result;
    }
}
```